# JMeter - Only run a subsequent test if the regular expression from the previous test can extract a certain value?

Tags: javascript, regex, jmeter

I'm running a series of webservice tests in JMeter and I was wondering if there's a way to skip a test if the regular expression extractor from the previous test can't extract a value due to an empty response or something. I understand that I'd need to use an If Controller but I can't figure out what I should put as the condition. The regular expression from the previous test is the following:

```
Reference Name: alarmid
Regular Expression: alarmStatus="raised" [^>]+ alarmId="(.+?)"
```

So if it can't find an alarm Id with a "raised" status, I want the next test to be skipped because ${alarmid} is an argument for it and will error with a 500 otherwise. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can possibly try to use combination of [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) and [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) with javascript condition: `${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok} (check if last sample succeeded)`.

Schema like below:

```
Sampler 1
    Response Assertion - to check if alarmId with alarmStatus="raised" is present in response;
    Regular Expression Extractor - your extractor to get alarmId;
If Controller
Condition = ${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}
    Sampler 2 - sampler that gets as argument extracted alarmId;
```

Response Assertion will set status of Sampler 1 to "failed" if no corresponding alarmId found, condition of If Controller will be evaluated as "false", Sampler 2 will be skipped.

Better way seems to be something like:

1. set value for "Default Value" field of [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor): `Default Value: NOT_FOUND` (this value will be set if regular expression does not match);
2. use javascript comparison of alarmId var with default value as condition of If Controller: `"${alarmId}"!="NOT_FOUND"` - if not equal than Sampler 2 is executed.

In this case you don't need to use Response Assertion.

Comment: This was just what I was looking for! I had no idea about these default values but it seems like they'll be pretty useful for what I'm doing. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables. Save a result of your regular expression to a variable and than use this  variable in IF CONTROLLER.

Syntax for variables is

```
${myVariable}
```

and this can be used everywhere in JMeter

Answer (score 0):

In your IF Controller, use:

```
"${alarmId}"  == "raised"
```